# File ended while scanning use of \@@@floatbox

Tags: ieeetran

I need to align a figure and a table in my two-column IEEE document. I've just started to handle the case in an `MWE`, as the following:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\title{xxx}

\maketitle

    \begin{figure*}
        \CenterFloatBoxes
        \begin{floatrow}
            \ffigbox
            {\includegraphics{rec.pdf}}
            {\caption{A caption for a figure in a figure and a table side by side}\label{fig:test}}
            \killfloatstyle
            \ttabbox
            {\begin{tabular}{|c||l|}
                    \hline
                    Event & Description\\
                    \hline
                    11 & \textbf{M1} generates a workpiece.\\
                    20 & \textbf{M2} takes a workpiece.\\
                    12~/~22 & Breakdown is occurred in \textbf{M1}~/~\textbf{M2}.\\
                    13~/~23 & \textbf{M1}~/~\textbf{M2} is repaired.\\
                    30~/~32 & \textbf{M1} increases \textbf{BUF1}~/~\textbf{BUF2}.\\
                    31~/~33 & \textbf{M2} decreases \textbf{BUF1}~/~\textbf{BUF2}.\\
                    \hline
                    91 & The reconfiguration $C^{1}_{\bm{G}} \rightarrow C^{2}_{\bm{G}}$ is requested.\\
                    93 & The reconfiguration $C^{2}_{\bm{G}} \rightarrow C^{1}_{\bm{G}}$ is requested.\\
                    \hline  
                \end{tabular}
            }
            {\caption{A caption for a table in a figure and a table side by side}\label{tab:test}}
        \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

which perfectly works:
[image]

Then, I tried the code in my main document, which includes many other packages in the preamble, such as:

```
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}    % To enable figures at the bottom of page
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{scrextend} % For referencing a footnote more than once
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow} % For two minipage alignment
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}
```

I placed the `figure*` environment right after the acknowledgment section, so the combination of the figure and the table should have been placed at the top of the last page (I even tested the snippet at different locations of the document). But when I compile my the document, the following error is raised:

> File ended while scanning use of \@@@floatbox.

And if I recompile it, the errors become two:

> Missing number, treated as zero. ...ncluding
>   {91}\footnotemark[\ref{note1}],
>
> File ended while scanning use of \@@@floatbox,

in addition to thrown warnings saying my citations are not defined. Note that before adding the recent snippet, everything could be compiled correctly.

Help?

Comment: I've glued your fragments together, however, there is no `acknowledgment` section etc. and there's no error, after fixing `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` (your ref.pdf file is not available to us)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: My main document is very long, consisting of 550 lines. It's impossible to upload it here. Have you ever heard of any reason behind `File ended while scanning use of \@@@floatbox` error? A clue about its meaning and its underlying reason might be helpful if you please.

Comment: `\@@@floatbox` is a `floatrow` doing, but I can't say what it is meant for or if `floatrow` is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
An alternative solution, without use of package `floatrow` and `dblfloatfix` and use `capt-of` package for settings table caption in `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of} % <--- for captions outside floats and for table caption in figure float
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}

\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page, instead of floatrow
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{xxx}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure*}[b]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics{rec.pdf}
    \caption{A caption for a figure in a figure and a table side by side}
\label{fig:test}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{A caption for a table in a figure and a table side by side}
\label{tab:test} 
    \begin{tabular}{|c||l|}
    \hline
Event & Description\\
    \hline
11 & \textbf{M1} generates a workpiece.\\
20 & \textbf{M2} takes a workpiece.\\
12~/~22 & Breakdown is occurred in \textbf{M1}~/~\textbf{M2}.\\
13~/~23 & \textbf{M1}~/~\textbf{M2} is repaired.\\
30~/~32 & \textbf{M1} increases \textbf{BUF1}~/~\textbf{BUF2}.\\
31~/~33 & \textbf{M2} decreases \textbf{BUF1}~/~\textbf{BUF2}.\\
    \hline
91 & The reconfiguration $C^{1}_{\bm{G}} \rightarrow C^{2}_{\bm{G}}$ is requested.\\
93 & The reconfiguration $C^{2}_{\bm{G}} \rightarrow C^{1}_{\bm{G}}$ is requested.\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum[2-11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I applied your solution to the document, but seemingly `stfloats` is not compatible with `dblfloatfix`. The compiler says: `Package dblfloatfix Error: Don't use the stfloats package!You're in big trouble now...`. I have to use `dblfloatfix` to keep one of my figures are the bottom of the page.

Comment: yes, they are incompatibility between this two packages, however, `stfloats` can replace `dblfloatfix`. it enable to put figure on the same page where is inserted and positioned on the bottom of the page (if there is enough space for it). See example in my MWE

Comment: Thanks. Commenting `dblfloatfix` erased all errors. Just a minor problem is that the table caption is changed to the Fig. Is is possible to have the `Table x` caption for the table, instead of `Fig. x`?

Comment: huh, i forgot on captions ... try to add `capt-of` package in preamble and for table instead `\caption{...}` write `\captionof{table}{...}`.